# How to trim a string after and before certain character for one column by a different where conditions in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have in my `dbo.table` column named `Gas`. 
I need to sum values nested inside this column.

The `Gas` has next values: 
`1:0.5;2:0.455;3:0.578;`

I need to trim values that are after `num` and before `;` -  0.5, 0.455, 0.578 etc;

So the desired query should be like:

```
SELECT user,
SUM(CASE WHEN 1: ; then trim(1: to ;) else 0 end) as case1
SUM(CASE WHEN 2: ; then trim(2: to ;) else 0 end) as case2
SUM(CASE WHEN 3: ; then trim(3: to ;) else 0 end) as case3
SUM(CASE WHEN 4: ; then trim(4: to ;) else 0 end) as case4
SUM(CASE WHEN 5: ; then trim(5: to ;) else 0 end) as case5
from table group by user;
```

Described table is like:

```
+---------+-------------------------+
|   user  |         gas             |
+---------+-------------------------+
|   adaf  |   1:0.5;2:0.455;3:0.578;|
|   rich  |    4:0.5;1:0.5;2:0.455; |
|   call  |    4:0.5;1:0.5;2:0.455; |
|   alen  |     6:0.78;7:89;1:789;  |
|  courney|     3:0.34;5:0.44;      |
+---------+-------------------------+
```

What I want to get is:

```
+---------+--------+---------+
| user    |  case 1|  case 2 | //etc
+---------+--------+---------+
|   adaf  |   0.5  |  0.455  |
|   rich  |   0.5  | 0.455   |
|   call  |   0.5  |  0.455  |
|   alen  |   789  |    0    |
|  courney|     0  |     0   |
+---------+--------+---------+
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Your table is using a horrible design. You are violating 1NF by sticking multiple values in a tuple like this. To add salt to the wound you have delimited data and each delimited element has two pieces of data. This is NOT how to handle data in a relational system. You should fix the design and this would no longer be an issue.

Comment: The `Case` statement is exactly the same for all scenarios, so the number before the `:` has no bearing on the results. Totally agree with @SeanLange. Very poor design.

Comment: So, that exactly what i supposed to hear from you guys before writing this question:) The trouble is that i'm not a designer of this DB, I'm just completing the task

Comment: well, is this even possible to pull those values from that column? using `substring` or other tool?

Comment: @ex1t3 -- the problem is we don't know what you want since the sql you posted does not make any sense.  You showed the source data -- now show what the expected output is after running your query.

Comment: Well the "designer" of this should be slapped for something so horrible. Do you have a fixed max number of possible values or does this have to be dynamic? There are many things you have to do here to make this work.

Comment: @SeanLange dynamic. I know only one thing: I have to pull 8 "types" (1:, 2: ,3:...8:) of gas to 8 different separated columns as i described above

Comment: Ugh....and the order of values is not even consistent. This is a nightmare to deal with.

Comment: @SeanLange -- clearly transforming to XML is best solution here.

Comment: So, can I somehow check if the `Gas` column contains '1:' then I can trim this value from `1:` to `;` and there will be same 7 cases just with another `num`

Comment: Whatever...i guess i'm on the way of big troubles, thank to all of you for derating and advices :)

Comment: The reason I have said your table is problematic is because it is seriously bad. When the table is designed poorly it makes pulling data back out of it increasingly difficult. However it is still possible to accomplish what you want. Part of that challenge was not getting a very clear definition of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This will produce the desired output for your sample data. This is using the splitter from Jeff Moden. you can find it here. It is super fast but has some features other splitters don't (the ordinal position of the value). http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

```
declare @Something table
(
    userName varchar(10)
    , gas varchar(100)
)

insert @Something values

('adaf', '1:0.5;2:0.455;3:0.578;')
, ('rich', '4:0.5;1:0.7;2:0.455;')
, ('call', '4:0.5;1:0.5;2:0.455;')
, ('alen', '6:0.78;7:89;1:789;')
, ('courney', '3:0.34;5:0.44;')

select userName
    , max(case when left(x.Item, 1) = '1' and x2.ItemNumber = 2 then x2.Item end) as case1
    , max(case when left(x.Item, 1) = '2' and x2.ItemNumber = 2 then x2.Item end) as case2
    , max(case when left(x.Item, 1) = '3' and x2.ItemNumber = 2 then x2.Item end) as case3
    , max(case when left(x.Item, 1) = '4' and x2.ItemNumber = 2 then x2.Item end) as case4
    , max(case when left(x.Item, 1) = '5' and x2.ItemNumber = 2 then x2.Item end) as case5
    , max(case when left(x.Item, 1) = '6' and x2.ItemNumber = 2 then x2.Item end) as case6
    , max(case when left(x.Item, 1) = '7' and x2.ItemNumber = 2 then x2.Item end) as case7
    , max(case when left(x.Item, 1) = '8' and x2.ItemNumber = 2 then x2.Item end) as case8
from @Something s
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(left(s.gas, len(gas) - 1), ';') x --have to use left here to remove the last delimiter
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(x.Item, ':') x2
group by s.userName
```

Comment: Thanks for your truly attention to my case. But I think it would be better to select a whole column and on the client side parse it. Using SQL methods is a very big mistake

Comment: Huh??? You stated you wanted this done in sql and then you state that doing it in sql is a big mistake.

Comment: sounds a bit mad, does not it?)

Answer (score 1):

No problem, if you are known about Data that would be how stored in Your Table.

Just try below short of `SQL` Command :

```
SELECT [user],
       SUBSTRING([case 1], CHARINDEX(':', [case 1])+1, LEN([case 1])) [case 1],
       SUBSTRING([case 2], CHARINDEX(':', [case 2])+1, LEN([case 2])) [case 2],
       SUBSTRING([case 3], CHARINDEX(':', [case 3])+1, LEN([case 3])) [case 3]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           [user],
           split.a.value('/M[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [case 1],
           split.a.value('/M[2]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [case 2],
           split.a.value('/M[3]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') [case 3]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT [user],
               CAST('<M>'+REPLACE(gas, ';', '</M><M>')+'</M>' AS XML) AS String
        FROM <table_name>
    ) AS A
    CROSS APPLY String.nodes('/M') AS split(a)
) AS A;
```

Output :

```
user    case 1  case 2  case 3
adaf    0.5     0.455   0.578
alen    0.78    89      789
call    0.5     0.5     0.455
courney 0.34    0.44    
rich    0.5     0.5     0.455
```

Answer (score 0):

With this type of problem (columns which contain internally structured data) you have a number of options and techniques:

1. Build or re-build your database model in a way that is well structured external to the fields not internal to them.  (as suggested by Sean Lange in the comments).
2. Build a view which parses the data (this often useful for simple paring like splitting first and last name)
3. Transform the data to XML (or JSON) which databases are better at parsing and querying.  You can also change your source system to deliver the data to the DB as XML if you need to send structured data.

Answer (score 0):

I will not say anything about perfect table design in your case, but this is what you can do (however if you want to have different columns for "Case1", "Case2" and so on you need to change it):

```
create table omg (
[user] varchar(20),
[gas] varchar(100)
);

insert into omg VALUES 
('adaf','1:0.5;2:0.455;3:0.578;'),
('rich','4:0.5;1:0.5;2:0.455;'),
('call','4:0.5;1:0.5;2:0.455;'),
('alen','6:0.78;7:89;1:789;'),
('courney','3:0.34;5:0.44;')
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
GO


SELECT [user], f.final_result, REPLACE(REPLACE(spl.splitdata, f.final_result , ''),':','') cases
FROM omg o
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[fnSplitString] (SUBSTRING(o.gas, 1, LEN(o.gas) -1),';') spl
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUBSTRING(spl.splitdata,CHARINDEX(':',spl.splitdata) + 1, LEN(spl.splitdata) - CHARINDEX(':',spl.splitdata)) final_result ) f
```

Comment: You should run away from the splitter immediately if not sooner. Using a loop to split strings is horrible for performance. Here are several much better choices. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: I would never use such code by myself. The question itself is terrible.

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea of Transforming the data to XML is a good idea. Its better than that mess of a table.

Comment: This is not an answer. You need to build your your reputation to be allowed to comment.